# If a user double-clicks on an item in a PyQt5 tree view, can we learn how many layers deep the item is?

Tags: pyqt5, treeview

Say I have a QStandardItemModel structured like so:

- Item 1

  - Item 1.1
- Item 2

  - Item 2.1

    - Item 2.1.1

If I view this model with a QTreeView and a signal doubleClicked is sent by the user, can I learn how many layes deep the item the user clicked on is? E.g. Item 1 and Item 2 would be a top layer. Item 1.1 would be one layer deep. Item 2.1.1 would be two layers deep etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recursively check the item's parent. Since you're receiving a QModelIndex, you can just check if the [`parent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#parent) is [valid](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#isValid).

So, just iterate the parent starting from the index received from the view.

```py
    def handleDoubleClicked(self, index):
        level = 0
        parent = index.parent()
        while parent.isValid():
            level += 1
            parent = parent.parent()
```

This can be similarly done for QStandardItemModel, by getting the related item from the index and then checking the [`parent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#parent):

> Returns the item's parent item, or `nullptr` if the item has no parent.

<sup>`nullptr` usually corresponds to `None` in Python.</sup>